# Cannot execute shell script from Java program

Tags: java, linux, shell

I have a java program which runs on Linux and attempts to call one shell script. This shell script tries to copy a local directory to another server. The way to call the script is :

```
bash copy_logs.sh "TestResults/07232015042652"
```

When i call this from linux terminal, the directory gets copied to remote server successfully. Now i want to execute this from Java program. My code snippet is as follows :

```
Sting direc = "07232015042652"
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash copy_logs.sh \"TestResults/"+direc+"\"");
```

When i run this, though i do not get any error or exception but the file never gets copied.

Contents of copy_logs.sh is as follows :

```
scp -r $TS test@192.168.199.57:/home/apacheweb/html/Weekly_Status/prov_check/
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "File copied successfully"
else
echo "Failed to copy"
```

I tried to print the result of execution by

```
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int i=0;
    try {
        while ((i=is.read())!=-1){
            sb.append((char)i);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

And i get the output : Failed to copy . Just wondering what can be root cause of this???

Comment: I'd consider using `ProcessBuilder` instead of  `Runtime.exec` as it will allow to specify each part of the command as a separate `String` which will help with quoting parameters (as you don't need to) and parameters with spaces.  May not fix the immediate problem, but will help resolve/eliminate other potential issues

Comment: as @MadProgrammer said, using `ProcessBuilder` will also make it easier to debug

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I already tried ProcessBuilder but it didn't helped :(

Comment: Didn't say it would solve the problem, but it will help you solve it in the long run, as if used correctly, it will remove much of the ambiguity that you get from `Runtime.exec`

Comment: Chillax madProgrammer, i am just updating you that it didn't worked, not blaming you Sir..

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by :

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "/bin/bash copy_logs.sh \"TestResults/"+directoryName+"\"");
 Process shell = pb.start();
```